Save API data(image) in cache or somewhere else
i tried to eliminate the loading time of category image. But I couldn't achieve that. when this screen                            is reloaded or reopened from another screen then the image is reloaded every time. how to resolve this issue?
CategoryProvider.dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:service_pro_user/Models/category_model.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class CategoryProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<CategoryModel> _categories = [];

  List<CategoryModel> get categories => _categories;

  Future<void> getCategories() async {
    final response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('http://20.52.185.247:8000/category'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final categoryData = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'] as List;
      _categories = categoryData.map((e) => CategoryModel.fromJson(e)).toList();

      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load categories');
    }
  }
}

Category.dart
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';
import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:service_pro_user/Models/category_model.dart';
import 'package:service_pro_user/Provider/category_provider.dart';
import 'package:service_pro_user/UI/home_screen/widgets/service.dart';

class Category extends StatefulWidget {
  const Category({super.key});

  @override
  State<Category> createState() => _CategoryState();
}

class _CategoryState extends State<Category> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Provider.of<CategoryProvider>(context, listen: false).getCategories();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<CategoryProvider>(
      builder: (context, categoryProvider, child) {
        if (categoryProvider.categories.isEmpty) {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        } else {
          final categoryData = categoryProvider.categories;
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  ),
                  child: const Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        'Categories',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                GridView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: categoryData.length,
                    gridDelegate:
                        const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                    ),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      final categories = categoryData[index];
                      String image = categories.image.toString();
                      image = image.replaceFirst('localhost', '20.52.185.247');
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) =>
                                  Service(category: categories),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: Container(
                                width: 180,
                                height: 150,
                                child: ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                  child: FittedBox(
                                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                    child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                        imageUrl: image,
                                        placeholder: (context, url) => Lottie.asset(
                                            'assets/lotties_animation/loading.json'),
                                        errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                                            Lottie.asset(
                                                'assets/lotties_animation/error.json')),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              categories.name.toString(),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}


Have you checked the cached_network_image package out?
Apart from that though, personally I use a riverpod future provider that returns an ImageProvider. It takes some time to fetch each image the first time obviously, but after that they're loaded instantly:
final categoryImageFutureProvider =
    FutureProvider.family<ImageProvider, String>(
  (ref, categoryImagePath) async {
    if (categoryImagePath.isNotEmpty) {
      try {
        final String url = await ImageController.getImageUrl(
            getCategoryImagePath(categoryImagePath: categoryImagePath));
        if (url.isNotEmpty) {
          return NetworkImage(url!);
        }
      } catch (exception) {
        ...
      }
    }
    return const ExactAssetImage("assets/icons/questionmark.png");
  },
);

and then call it like so:
final categoryImage =
    ref.watch(categoryImageFutureProvider(category.imageName ?? '')).valueOrNull;

...
...child: ImageIcon(categoryImage);


you are wrong. please send me the code used  in  state management provider.
